# If not a custom taxonomy on loop on WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom taxonmy called Editions that allows a user to select custom archives for a magazine like website. To create the current edition site they add them to a category called This Edition, and then archive them using the taxonomy as need be. The client wants posts that have been tagged with this custom taxonomy to not appear on the posts page (but they remain in that category though)

Any ideas how I could do this? I'm assuming some simple if(!in_somecrap) logic will work, but what would the code be and how would I integrate it into the category loop.

Thanks/

Comment: Is there anyway to exclude the taxonomy using Query_posts?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to query all 'normal' posts, use;

```
$query = WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post'));
```